# Nuget Packages exclude version in folder naming

Tags: c#, git, teamcity, nuget

currently i have a project that has nuget packages that are placed in folders according to their different version number

Example packages/EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0/..

Is there a way to update the packages and have the folders renamed to exclude the version numbers 
i.e for the above we have packages/EntityFramework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, NuGet doesn't support installing packages without their version number. There's a work item tracking this here: [Issue #1522](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1522). Please comment/vote to bump the priority.

One way to help with many related scenarios is to enable [NuGet Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

Answer (score 19):

Yes http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference

> ExcludeVersion    If set, the destination folder will contain only the package name, not the version number

Comment: This link no longer documents ExcludeVersion.  Would love to know if there's an archive out there!

Comment: I think the link only refers to current version, whereas the 3.x versions did allow this with -excludeVersion.

Comment: ExcludeVersion is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install

Comment: Note that ExcludeVersion has buggy behavior - if you change your packages.config (such as getting latest or switching branches) and execute "nuget install packages.config -ExcludeVersion", nuget will silently fail to update - it will claim to install the new version, but the old version will remain in place.