# Svn externals to Nuget migration - concerns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, nuget

I'm migrating from Svn externals feature to `nuget` with a huge project and so far it looks like a bad decision. One of my solution contains 70 projects where most of them contains the same common references (nuget packages).
Previous structure was a common Lib folder per solution which contained all references controlled by `svn externals` so whenever I wanted to update a version I just updated numbers in tortoise svn and clicked update - quick job.
Currently when I do it from inside Visual Studio it takes 10-20 times longer because I suspect it removes the previous version of package directory from packages, adds new directory, updates `packages.config` version and updates `csproj` path. So if I update 7 packages in 70 projects and I have visual studio open it will take much longer. The alternative is to close solution and call nuget update in `command-line` but it's rather a workaround. Previously path was the same, concept of `packages.config` didn't exist so the only change was a few lines of code in a text file where we come to the next conclusion - source control changes. Whenever I do an update there is a huge amount of changes which needs to be checked in into source control and I find it a bit messy. I found that there is a flag for `nuget install -ExcludeVersion` which will exclude version from path so csproj won't be changed and it's a big advantange. Is it a good convention to use it? Is there are support for Visual Studio to use it automatically whenever I install a package? Is there a way to mark a nuget package as "Ignore version in path"? As far as I know the answers for these questions is no, no, no. How do you handle using nuget in bigger projects? Please me know if there is something I can read about nuget how to handle it in bigger projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's address each issue one by one. Your first question states:

> Is it a good convention to use it?

This is subject to opinion. If it will break your project to use the `ExcludeVersion` option on install, then you can't use it. Otherwise, it saves you 70 files on push. The second question states:

> Is there are support for Visual Studio to use it automatically whenever I install a package?

As far as I can tell (and I may be wrong), there is no way to do this. However, this is going off of quick research, and more information may be found deep inside of the [Nuget Config File Defaults](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-defaults) (I could not find such a configuration).

I am a little confused as to what you mean by

> Is there a way to mark a nuget package as "Ignore version in path"?

However, it seems that you mean what **Colonel Panic** asked in this question: [Nuget Packages exclude version in folder naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328516/nuget-packages-exclude-version-in-folder-naming), in which the answer is no. And lastly, you briefly ask the question:

> How do you handle using nuget in bigger projects?

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is quite simple: you can't (at least not effectively). Nuget themselves say this in a [blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20141010/nuget-is-broken.html) from  October 10, 2014. If you read underneath their "Harmful consequences" section, you can see a lot of the issues that you are running into.

Alright, now onto the solution. I have run into a similar issue with Nuget in the past, and the solution was quite simple. All I had to do to minimize the time was to use Git from command line using Visual Studio's `.gitignore` (Svn I believe would work too). I know we would all appreciate Nuget to work in these instances; however, this is not the case. As you already use svn, I would suggest not changing. After all, Nuget is really only a macro inside of Visual Studios working on a solution basis.

Comment: 1. I just found out that -ExcludeVersion doesn't work as I expected. It adds package to project directory without including it in packages.config.
2. Not important.
3. I wanted to exclude version when build server builds and packs a package instead of when installing it. It's not important because it  doesn't work.
4. We are going to migrate from svn to git that's why I wanted to use appropriate package management which is nuget. I can't believe using nuget is not the case after so many years of existence... I'll give it a try anyway and see what happens. Thanks mate

Comment: I just found out that I can take advantage of project.json in WPF app. Is it recommended?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my question is project.json. I wasn't aware that I can use it in every project even in WPF. https://oren.codes/2016/02/08/project-json-all-the-things/